# create a form for several entities symfony2.3 (best practice)

Tags: forms, validation, doctrine, twig, symfony-2.3

I want to create a form from several entities (article, category, adress, attributes, gallery) with custom fields (remove fields, customize css, ...),
what is the best practice with Symfony2 and forms
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you want to you an embedded collection of forms to do this. An example shown bellow:

```
        $builder->add('subject','text', array(
            'required' => false,
            ));
        $builder->add('body','textarea', array(
            'required' => false,
            ));
        $builder->add('files','collection', array(
            'type' => new DocumentForm(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'label' => false,
            ));
```

This form binds to my message entity, however, you still have a collection type which relates to a different form that is attached to my file entity.

You want to embed entities and forms. You can find more information on this here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: after receiving the form how persists in several entities

Comment: In your control you will get your request like: $request = $this->request(); Then you will create a form like $form = $this->createForm( new MyForm() ); Your form will then automatically create an entity and bind the requested data to it when you call: $form->handleRequest(). There are some form calls that you can do to then retrieve your entities. You can also bind to an existing entity, but thats probably not what you want to do.

Comment: how to display the form 'CategoryType' in the form 'ArticleType' in twig without using javascript

Comment: is it the best practice to customize my form in the twig and after i will handle the request in the controller?

Comment: Best practice is whatever keeps good design principle in mind. If there's a good solution that works for you, just use it. And please upvote and choose this answer if it helped you.